# Sqlite3 - node js insert multiple rows in two tables, lastID not working

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, node-modules

I know there are many solutions provided regarding multiple insertion in `sqlite3` but I am looking for efficient method in which data is getting inserted into two tables and data of second table is dependent on first table. This is a `node js` application.

I have two tables `programs` and `tests` in sqlite3. Table `tests` contains id of `programs` i.e. one program can contains multiple tests.

**The suggested method on official page** of `sqlite3` module is as follows:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

db.close();
```

As In my requirement I have to insert data in tow tables so **I am using the following code:**

```
var programData = resp.program_info; // contains complete data of programs and tests
db1.run("INSERT INTO programs (`parent_prog_id`, `prog_name`, `prog_exercises`, `prog_orgid`, `prog_createdby`, `prog_created`, `prog_modified`, `prog_status`)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",prog.parent_program_id,prog.programName, JSON.stringify(prog), req.session.org_id, prog.created_by, prog.created_at, prog.updated_at, prog.program_status,function(err){
if(err){
       throw err;
}else{
var count           = 1;
var step2PostedData = prog;
for (i in step2PostedData.testsInfo) {
  var c = 0;

   for(j in step2PostedData.testsInfo[i]){

    var obj = Object.keys(step2PostedData.testsInfo[i])[c];

    db1.prepare("INSERT INTO `tests` ( `parent_name`,`test_name`, `test_alias`, `sequences`, `duration`, `prog_id`, `org_id`, `test_createdby`,  `test_created`, `test_modified`, `test_status`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
    .run(count, obj,
         step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].alias,
         step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].sequences,
         step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].duration,
         this.lastID, // using this I am getting program id
         req.session.org_id, 
         prog.created_by, 
         prog.created_at, 
         prog.updated_at,
         prog.program_status);

    c++;
    count++;
    }
}
```

**Now, my query is If I am using the suggested method then I am not getting last inserted program id from `programs` table.** without callback.

e.g. If I use the following code;

```
var stmt = db1.prepare("INSERT INTO programs (`parent_prog_id`, `prog_name`, `prog_exercises`, `prog_orgid`, `prog_createdby`, `prog_created`, `prog_modified`, `prog_status`)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

var stmt2 = db1.prepare("INSERT INTO `tests` ( `parent_name`,`test_name`, `test_alias`, `sequences`, `duration`, `prog_id`, `org_id`, `test_createdby`, `test_created`, `test_modified`, `test_status`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

programData.forEach(function(prog){
    // Inserts data in programs table
    stmt.run(prog.parent_program_id,prog.programName, JSON.stringify(prog), req.session.org_id, prog.created_by, prog.created_at, prog.updated_at, prog.program_status);

     for (i in step2PostedData.testsInfo) {
       var c = 0;
       for(j in step2PostedData.testsInfo[i]){
         var obj = Object.keys(step2PostedData.testsInfo[i])[c];
         stmt2.run(
                   count, 
                   obj, 
                   step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].alias,
                   step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].sequences,  
                   step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].duration,
                   'what should be there',// How to get last program inserted ID there   
                   req.session.org_id,
                   prog.created_by, 
                   prog.created_at, 
                   prog.updated_at,
                   prog.program_status);
      } // inner for loop ends
  } // outer for loop ends
  stmt.finalize();
  stmt2.finalize();
});
```

- If I use `this.lastID` that returns null, obviously as no callback is
  now.
- If I use `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` then 
  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid is not defined error.
- If I use `last_insert_rowid()` then last_insert_rowid() is not
  defined.

**Query:**

How can I insert last inserted program id there, Currently I am getting last program id as null?

**Edit:**

If and only if using callback is the way or method to get the last ID then I will keep my code running as it is currently. Can anyone please suggest how can I increase the speed of insertion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) is a part of the C API.
[last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) is an SQL function.

If the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) tells you that `lastID` is valid inside the callback, then you must use the callback.
Just move all the child INSERTs into the completion callback of the parent INSERT.

(The suggested code is not intended to show how to get the last inserted ID; it just demonstrates that the values actually have been inserted.)

Comment: I am already using in callback but speed is so slow of insertion. Or if you are suggesting some thing different then please edit answer with the code.

Comment: How to speed up insertions would be a different question.

Comment: This question has been answered many times on SO. (Short answer: use a single transaction around all statements.)

Comment: node sqlite3 does not supports transactions. can you please update my question or give answer with use of transaction in my code??

Comment: I am using sqlite3 module of node js

Comment: BEGIN TRANSACTION etc. are SQL statements.